# Eliminating space from text outputted to a file through batch command

Tags: batch-file

```
for /l %x in  (1, 1, 10) do echo|set /p= SampleOut,>log.txt
```

I am trying to output

```
SampleOut,SampleOut,SampleOut...
```

to a text file , but with above command i only get

```
SampleOut, SampleOut, SampleOut...
```

How do i remove that space being outputted to that text file?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 10) do echo|set /p "=SampleOut,">>log.txt
```

Always use `"` double quotes in `set "varname=varvalue"` to avoid problems with undesired leading and/or trailing spaces in both `varname` and `varvalue`. For instance, next `set` commands lead to different results:

```
set "varname=varvalue"
set "varname =varvalue"
set "varname= varvalue"
set "varname=varvalue "
```

Answer (score 2):

```dos
(for /l %x in (1, 1, 10) do @set /p"=SampleOut,") <nul >>log.txt
```

There are three changes to your code:

- `set` command is now quoted to avoid problems with undesired spaces
- The full `for` command is redirected to the log file. This way the output file is only opened once, all data written and then the file is closed. In your code the open/write/close is executed for each iteration.
- `echo|set` has been removed. The problem with the pipe is that it is created between processes, so both sides of the pipe need a separate `cmd` instance to execute the internal commands and for each iteration two processes need to be created.

Executing a `set /p` with its input stream reading from `nul` device has the same result that your pipe, echoing the prompt value without the ending carriage return and line feed.

In the posted code I have redirected the input stream of the full `for` to avoid having to do it in each iteration.